# Perhaps do not oblige users to read and understand your privacy policy and cookies policy?

Tags: feature-request, terms-of-service, sign-up

I finally reached the end of the processing of your terms and conditions. They are quite long, although they do have the advantage of applying to several useful sites.

One possible improvement, is to change the agreement such that it doesn't oblige users to read and understand your cookies policy and privacy policy. Such obliging occurs both in the user agreement, **as well as in the homepage footer banner**.

It appears that normally websites don't oblige users in such ways. The privacy policy—for example—is often just there for the user if he or she wishes to review it: there's often no forcing users into both the reading of it and the understanding of it.

These two policies (cookies policy and privacy policy) have no contractually-articulated user obligations (it appears). This often appears to be the case with such policy documents. Therefore, users don't have to restrict or change their behaviour as part of their formal obligations, in respect of these two policies of yours. They could most likely just skip reading them without hurting their compliance with your user agreement, apart from the compliance to your insistence that users read and understand these policies.

If it takes a user one hour to read these two policy documents, and you have 100,000 users, that will end-up being 100,000 man-hours spent on reading these two policy documents, which could be an awful waste of resources. And that's being quite optimistic in respect of the time it takes to read them.

I advise you not to oblige users to read these two documents, both in order to reduce wastage by your userbase, as well as to improve your product and service offerings.

Comment: Your points are reasonable, OTOH, I feel all users should at least read the section on Content & Licensing https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing so that they're aware of the issues related to the ownership, copyright, and licensing of material they and other users post on the network, and their obligations when they copy any material to or from the network.

Comment: I read the first, maybe 3 words. I just have long-documents itis, and cannot read the entirety of it. And come on, they're just technical stuff that exist to enforce laws. It's like reading every single word in the constitution.

Comment: I wouldn't mind reading the US constitution if I were American... True that they're often very technical; part of the content of user agreements is often based upon complying with laws and regulations. I'm wanting to change the culture around user agreements so that they become friendlier to users...

Answer (score 27):

Wait, those things are actually meant to be read?

I always thought they were padding to make clicking the "I agree" button more exciting.

---

Jokes aside, nobody *actually* reads documents like that. They're just there so that in the unlikely case someone does file some ridiculous legal claim, they've got something to point at and tell the user to sod off.

In case of the Cookie Policy, there's actually a legal requirement in the EU to make the user very aware of what the policy is:

> To comply with the regulations governing cookies under the GDPR and the ePrivacy Directive you must:
>
> 1. Receive users’ consent before you use any cookies except strictly necessary cookies.
> 2. Provide accurate and specific information about the data each cookie tracks and its purpose in plain language before consent is received.
> 3. Document and store consent received from users.
> 4. Allow users to access your service even if they refuse to allow the use of certain cookies
> 5. Make it as easy for users to withdraw their consent as it was for them to give their consent in the first place.
>
> ([source](https://gdpr.eu/cookies/), I added the numbers)

Points 1 and 2 together make it so you're *required* to show (make available) that wall of text to the user, before they can click on "I accept".

Whether you *actually read it* or not it entirely up to you.

Comment: Don't think it is an EU requirement to insist upon users both reading and understanding the cookie policy. Might be an EU requirement for websites to have cookies policies, but unlikely to be such that there has to be insistence that users read them, let alone understand them too. I'm the person who actually reads the documents [because of religious beliefs]. It's the reason why I'm switching to products and services based in the EU, because of the EU culture appearing to be friendlier re. such things. US culture is supposed to be quite litigious--perhaps why many user agreements are this way?

Comment: Nobody is claiming reading those walls of text is absolutely mandatory. That's just a rule you made up, free will is still a thing, mate. You're absolutely free to skip reading the thing and just click "I accept". That's what everyone does, any way. I've updated my answer. Your implication that people are __"Required to read"__ is just your interpretation of what's going on.

Comment: Ignorance of the rules is never a good defence.

Comment: "Required to read" as in the provider of the service articulates that you are required to read... It constructs a legal defence or prosecution argument for the provider in court, if the user did not read the terms....

Comment: This implies you'd be stupid enough to sue the site for something that's covered in the terms. In that sense it's a good idea to read the terms... But that ___still does not mean___ they expect every single average joe to read the entire document. This is how the entire internet works, mate. Wall of text -> "I agree" -> website's got their ass legally covered. Only lawyers care whether or not you actually read that, and that really won't matter unless you for some stupid reason end up in court, somehow.

Comment: To summarize: You're trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist. It's your own choice whether or not you read it.

Comment: The simple fact is, @MarkFernandes, is that if you don't want to accept the terms without reading them then yes, you need to read them, however, if you are happy to "trust" SE terms without reading them you are also completely free to do so. I would suggest that millions of people a day accept terms and conditions that don't read as they are literally everywhere, from visiting websites, purchasing a subscription service, buying a new electrical equipment with a warranty, switching electricity provider, buying insurance, etc, etc, etc. That all have T&Cs 99.9% of people don't read.

Comment: You all make interesting & worthwhile points. Re. going to court, you may not be the one who instigates proceedings, the provider may be the one. I consider that if you are going to get some high-quality service mostly completely free (like the Stack Exchange network), then it's not much to ask for users to abide by your user agreement. Also, if an entity clearly displays a pop-up message on the homepage of a website insisting that you read and understand their terms, I would have thought that the provider expected you to do so--don't you think?

Comment: Again I emphasise that US culture (which is connected to the whole anglophile world) is particularly litigious, and that this might be part of the problem. The EU seems better for such things. Trusting the terms of a provider, isn't just about trusting the provider--it's also about the provider trusting you, trusting that you aren't going to abuse their services. The financial crash appears to have occurred due to ppl not respecting contractual obligations, obligations regarding whether it was okay to sign ppl up to mortgages.

Comment: It's true that overly long terms and conditions appear to be almost everywhere, but that doesn't remove the aspect that people are entering into legally-binding contracts that most people would consider have moral implications. I handle such things in a variety of ways, including, for example, making online purchases only from a small few providers for whom I have processed their terms (I use Amazon for example). Using the Stack Exchange network of sites is good because one set of terms applies to many useful websites.

Comment: Mate, all of that is your personal opinion. Nobody is holding you at gunpoint to read those walls of text. There's ___nothing___ to fix here. If you're _actually_ worried about getting sued by SE, which is even more absurd than it sounds, then by all means, dig through the text. @MarkFernandes. This is the internet. The fact that you're on it means a shitload of companies know more about you than you'd like to know, any way. You're putting ___waaaaay___ too much value into the terms of a reputable programming Q&A site.

Comment: I mean, the profile picture you have uploaded here alone is enough to find your LinkedIn and Medium profiles, which in turn leads us to your Facebook profile and even your ___home address___ through an IT outsourcing website... SE's terms are the least of your concerns, @Mark.

Comment: My home address is also my business address. As such, it isn't confidential. I don't drink the "cool aid" and hype over data protection issues. Sometimes people knowing who you are can be a good thing.

Comment: @Cerbrus: you misunderstand my intentions. I'm trying to help Stack Overflow on a business-level. I'm not worried about my reading the terms... and I'm not telling anyone else to read the terms.

Comment: You're trying to help them fix a problem that doesn't exits.

Answer (score 14):

The important part is **accepting** the agreements.  Not many people expect all users to read the entirety of the agreements for the various websites, services, and products that they interact with.  As you rightly said, it takes a long time.

The words are there as reference.  If you're concerned about a particular aspect of online life (privacy for example), you can read that portion and accept/reject on those terms.

Comment: You make a good point about acceptance of terms. Probably true about not many ppl expecting users to read them all. My religious beliefs dictate that often I do need to read them all--the important part for me is reaching some level of compliance, and unfortunately that appears often to mean that I have to read them all.

Answer (score 4):

> It appears that normally websites don't oblige users in such ways.

This isn't true of sites (or apps) that handle PII. If you're just visiting a blog, sure. But I cannot recall a time where I've created an account someplace where I wasn't asked to read the ToS and Privacy Policy. It's very common; Stack Exchange is not an outlier here.

A better request would be to ask for a shorter, simpler explanation of the terms. I think I've only seen it in a couple of places, for example [GitHub's Privacy Policy has a summary](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/site-policy/github-privacy-statement). If you just want the gist or want something that's easier to understand, I think that's a good compromise. (They do make it clear that you're agreeing to the full, legal text and not just the summary.)

Cerbrus and Snow are correct that most people never read these, which is how you get [people agreeing to give up their first born in exchange for free wifi](https://www.npr.org/2019/03/08/701417140/when-not-reading-the-fine-print-can-cost-your-soul).

Comment: My experience has been different: most sites and apps do not oblige users to read & understand the privacy policy. I'm the "odd ball" who actually tries to reach some level of compliance with user agreements without relying on "wing and prayer" principles [because of religious beliefs]. So I've looked at lots of user agreements and they don't oblige users (in general) in this way re. the privacy policy. It's true that often user agreements oblige users to read the main user agreement, but this wasn't part of my concerns.

Comment: I also like to read the tiny type. I maintain that they're not an outlier in this but even if they were, I don't see a functional difference between being asked/told you're agreeing to a policy and being asked to read it.

Comment: Well from a legal point of view, if you were required to read the terms and you then ended-up breaking the terms, that would probably be seen as a worse violation than if you were only required to accept them but still broke the terms in the same way. Insisting upon reading likely means that it's more important that you keep to them.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "worse violation". Do you mean that the the requirement to read them implies the penalty for violating the ToS would be harsher or do you just mean that it implies the company is more likely to actually enforce their ToS.

Comment: probably both. Without the pop-up, the ToS becomes less important, and violations would likely be tolerated more.

Answer (score 2):

You're not obligated to read these agreements - just to accept them.

It's your choice whether you want to be informed as to what you're accepting - if you do, then you need to read them in their entirety. If you don't care, as most people, then don't read them.

Comment: Well to accept them, may mean that you need to read them. Entering into a contract with little hope of fulfilling your side of the bargain, isn't a good idea.